# How to keep content inside container when using push and pull classes with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use the push/pull classes where they seem to work like I intended, but they do not stay inside the container. How can I fix this?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-push-4">
            <p style="color:black;">sidebar</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-pull-8">
            <p style="color:black;">main content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <p style="color:black;">main content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <p style="color:black;">sidebar</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/wvbSlom5BU

Comment: http://www.schmalz.io/2014/10/08/Column-Ordering-in-Bootstrap/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pushing a column of width 4 by 4, and a column of width 8 by 8. You need to push the column of 4 widths by 8, and pull the column of 8 widths by 4.

**[BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/qOpWoTTPbq)**

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-push-8">
            <p style="color:black;">sidebar</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-pull-4">
            <p style="color:black;">main content</p>
        </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <p style="color:black;">main content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <p style="color:black;">sidebar</p>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) for these classes.

You also don't need multiple container divs for the rows, just one.